# Special characters not working in PDF title but in PDF content when using wkhtmltopdf with php

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf for my content within a Laravel app.

Controller.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @todo
 */
public function pdf($regionCode, $langCode, Model $model)
{
    $locale = LocalisationServiceProvider::getLocale($regionCode, $langCode);

    $pdfFileName = $this->buildPdfFileName($model->id, $locale);

    if (Storage::disk('root')->exists('public/storage/wkhtmltopdf/' . $pdfFileName)) {
        return response()->file(public_path('/storage/wkhtmltopdf/' . $pdfFileName));
    }

    $view = view('model.pdf', compact('model', 'locale'));
    $viewRendered = $view->render();

    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'binary' => env('WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY_PATH'),
        'ignoreWarnings' => ('production' === env('APP_ENV')),
        'disable-smart-shrinking',
        'title' => $model->title . ' - Site.pdf',
        'encoding' => 'utf-8',
    ]);

    $pdf->addPage($viewRendered);

    if (!$pdf->saveAs(public_path('/storage/wkhtmltopdf/' . $pdfFileName))) {
        $error = $pdf->getError();
        // @todo log
        return response('An error occured', 500);
    }

    if (!$pdf->send($model->title . ' - Site.pdf', true)) {
        $error = $pdf->getError();
        return response('An error occured', 500);
    }
}

/**
 * @todo
 */
public function buildPdfFileName($id, $locale)
{
    return 'foobar_' . $id . '_' . $locale . '.pdf';
}
```

pdf.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas" class="position-relative">

            @hasSection('header')
                <header id="header">
                    @yield('header')
                </header>
            @endif

            @hasSection('main')
                <main role="main" id="main-content">
                    @yield('main')
                </main>
            @endif

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PDF looks fine (except CSS issues, different matter). On my local machine, the PDF that gets send to the browser tab, also shows the correct browser tab title, meaning special chars are displayed correctly in the browser tab (like umlauts). When I want to save the file, the suggested file name in the OS' save prompt is the same and also looks fine.

On production however, the title in the browser tab misses all special chars while when saving the file it suggests the correct file name again. So "können" for instance is displayed as "knnen" in the browser tab but the save prompt shows "können".

On both machines runs `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt)`.

All I found in previous threads is adding utf encoding as meta and adding it as option, which I both did and locally it does work.

PS: `buildPdfFileName` is only used for the internal pdf name that gets saved and loaded locally, it is not the title/ filename suggestion.

Comment: @KJ hm I guess that makes sense. The production runs on debian though an `!` is allowed but I guess its different from `ö ü ä` - or is it? Ill have the version updated and see again

Comment: @KJ well again, this is not yet the actual filename but the title the browser tab shows when viewing the PDF inline (maybe its the same origin, I dont know). Replacing these characters ofc has a different effect, I wonder if the OS is actually the problem... Ill try some more

Comment: what do you get from `var_dump(base64_encode($pdfFileName));`  both on production and dev with the sam filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When displaying a PDF, most browsers show the PDF title (when defined) in the tab title.

To set the PDF title, you are using the `title` option, which is passed to wkhtmltopdf on the command line.

First, you should check if `$model->title` is encoded in UTF-8 or not.

Another possible explanation for the issue is that the PHP process has no `LANG` environment variable defined. In that case,
the default locale is `C`, which supports only the ASCII encoding. All non-ASCII characters are considered invalid. A way to fix it is to add this before running wkhtmltopdf :

```php
putenv('LANG=de_DE.UTF-8');
```

Alternatively, you can define the PDF title via the `<title>` HTML tag. Just remove the `title` option and add the `<title>` tag to your HTML page. This is the most reliable solution because it avoids transmitting non-ASCII characters on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is an encoding issue of the production environment on which your code runs.

In particular, also because you said that your OS handles properly the file name when downloading it from production, on production you should check if the script that render the webpage/pdf is set with the correct encoding for the output to send to the browser (in your case the pdf).

Usually, the browser uses the encoding delivered by the web page.

You can try these attempts:

- in addition to set the `Content-Type` in the rendered HTML, try to set it also in the PHP script, before sending any output to the browser.
- try to encode the title: `'title' => urlencode($model->title . ' - Site.pdf'),`
- set it as wkhtmltopdf option:

  ```
  $pdf = new Pdf([
      'binary' => env('WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY_PATH'),
      'ignoreWarnings' => ('production' === env('APP_ENV')),
      'disable-smart-shrinking',
      'title' => $model->title . ' - Site.pdf',
      // 'encoding' => 'utf-8',
      'options' => array(
          'encoding' => 'utf-8'
      ),
  ]);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

After going through all suggestions, the only thing that worked for me was to set the title via `<title>` tag within the base template and remove the title option when creating a new pdf class:

```
<?php

$pdf = new Pdf([
    'binary' => env('WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY_PATH'),
    'ignoreWarnings' => ('production' === env('APP_ENV')),
    'disable-smart-shrinking',
    'encoding' => 'utf-8',
]);

$pdf->addPage($viewRendered);

if (!$pdf->send($model->title . ' - Sitename.pdf', true)) {
    $error = $pdf->getError();
    return response('An error occured', 500);
}
```

This correctly shows the title in the browser tab and when saving has the correct filename suggestion.

What didnt work:

1.) Set the content type via htaccess:

`<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/pdf$#">   Header always set Content-Type "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8" </If>`
This didnt even show in my response headers and had no effect at all. I probably did it wrong.

2.) This lead to a server error:

```
// 'encoding' => 'utf-8',
'options' => array(
    'encoding' => 'utf-8'
),
```

3.) `putenv('LANG=de_DE.UTF-8');` had no effect (probably it already is utf8).

4.) All my strings were already utf-8 encoded. Using urlencode within the title option did show urlencoded strings instead of umlauts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to

- PDF or
- user language or
- means of serving

It's traditional NOT to use non-Latin UTF characters in URLs because they need conversion into "safe" ranges for different OS, locality, applications, etc, and Latin/US is historically Universally Resource Location friendly. Here same file 2 different browsers 2 different results

[image]

When found locally still 2 different outcomes

[image]

**Each browser is responsible for choosing tab titles**. Note here the tab in the middle is the same as all the others, but browser asked if I wished to change it from German to English. the last example shows the **Tab is "Untitled" without an HTML carrier until after the downloaded PDF is returned to the browser.**

[image]

So towards your answer, the OS handles filenames during production. Here all is well, but **browsers decide for themselves based of loaded html title** or 2nd any other over-ride like users choice of tab name or a hint from RE-loaded.PDF, where the PDF string will have been correctly injected as PDF BOM-UTF-16BE by wkHTML as say `/Title (þÿ T i t e l   k ö n n e n   f u n k t i o n i e r e n)`    then its up to the browser to convert that into a semblance of human readable string English, German UTF-8 URL encoded or whatever.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding encoding to binary path solve UTF-8 issue

```bash
WKHTMLTOPDF_BINARY_PATH="/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --encoding UTF-8"
```

Remember to use correct path to wkhtmltopdf, above example path based on debian installation.

```
apt install wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: I am not downvoting this because it might help others but this solution is described everywhere and as I described encoding was not the issue